# ORACLE PLS-00049: bad bind variable

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Создал триггер для таблицы new_computation_mt4

В ней есть следующие поля:

- N_COMPUTATION – идентификатор начисления N_CLIENT – лицевой счет
  абонента
- D_COMPUTATION – дата начисления N_INFO_HOT – текущие    показания
  счетчика горячей воды
- N_INFO_COLD – текущие показания    счетчика    холодной воды
- N_DIFFERENCE_HOT – разница текущих и    предыдущих    показаний
  счетчика горячей воды
- N_DIFFERENCE_COLD –    разница    текущих и    предыдущих показаний
  счетчика холодной воды
- N_TARIFF –       идентификатор тарифов на    горячую и холодную воду
- N_SUM_HOT    –       начисление за горячую воду за текущий период
- N_SUM_HOT – начисление      за холодную воду за текущий период
- N_DEBT    – долг на начало периода
- N_PAY – оплата за предыдущий    период
- N_TOTAL – итоговая сумма    на конец    месяца

Задание состоит в том чтоб после инсерта в таблицу поля N_DIFFERENCE_COLD и N_DIFFERENCE_HOT посчитались автоматически найдя разницу между текущими(введенными) показателями счетчика (N_INFO_COLD и N_INFO_HOT) и за предыдущий месяц.

Сам триггер:

```
create or replace trigger comp_complete_hot
after insert on new_computation_mt4
begin
  :N_DIFFERENCE_HOT := get_diff_hot(N_INFO_HOT, D_COMPUTATION, N_CLIENT);
end;​
```

Функция get_diff_hot:

```
create or replace function get_diff_hot(new_info number, datte date, client number)
  return number
is 
  diff number;
begin
  select n_info_hot 
  into   diff 
  from   computation 
  where  d_computation = add_months(datte, -1) 
  and    n_client = client;

  diff := new_info - diff;
  return diff;
end;​
```

Оракл выдаёт ошибку:

> Compilation failed, line 2 (15:07:52) The line numbers associated with
>   compilation errors are relative to the first BEGIN statement. This
>   only affects the compilation of database triggers. PLS-00049: bad bind
>   variable 'N_DIFFERENCE_HOT'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка прямо так и говорит "неправильная привязываемая переменная N_DIFFERENCE_HOT". И она действительно не правильная, во первых такая переменная не объявлена, во вторых с двоеточием переменные передаются снаружи и в триггерах их быть не может.

Видимо вы хотели написать `:NEW.N_DIFFERENCE_HOT`, а так же `:NEW.N_INFO_HOT` и т.п. По крайней мере поля изменяемой таблицы (новые значения) доступны именно через `:NEW.`. После того как вы это исправите у вас будут еще две ошибки. Во первых данные в колонках таблицы может менять только `BEFORE` триггер, а вы используете `AFTER` и данные конкретной записи доступны только в построчном триггере (`FOR EACH ROW`).

Итого, с учетом вышесказанного:

```
create or replace trigger comp_complete_hot
BEFORE insert on new_computation_mt4 FOR EACH ROW
begin
  :NEW.N_DIFFERENCE_HOT := get_diff_hot(:NEW.N_INFO_HOT, :NEW.D_COMPUTATION, :NEW.N_CLIENT);
end;​
```

P.S. Если не предполагается вызывать функцию `get_diff_hot` еще где нибудь, я бы рекомендовал перенести ее логику непосредственно в триггер, для снижения накладных расходов на вызов функции.